# django email registration - No module named _ssl

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to implement the Django registration reset functionality and I'm using the following as my *password-reset-email.html* which I've downloaded from [github](https://github.com/bitmazk/django-registration-email/blob/master/registration_email/templates/registration/password_reset_email.html)

```
{% load i18n %}{% load url from future %}{% autoescape off %} {% blocktrans %}You're receiving this e-mail because you requested a password reset for your user account at {{ site_name }}.{% endblocktrans %}

{% trans "Please go to the following page and choose a new password:" %} {% block reset_link %} {{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm' uidb36=uid token=token %} {% endblock %}

{% trans "Thanks for using our site!" %}

{% blocktrans %}The {{ site_name }} team{% endblocktrans %}

{% endautoescape %}
```

I'm getting `No module named _ssl` error and I don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've downgraded my version of python from 2.7.11 to 2.7.9 and that seems to have sorted this issue, however, it has raised a new one!.

Comment: What is the new one?

Comment: On the development server (my laptop) it is: `[Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it`.  When I load it into Goggle Appengine it is `[Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known`

Comment: I understand the error on the development machine because I believe that is due to not having set up the email server on it.  I'm not sure about the Google Appengine issue